# Does "remembered to" mean that the action was done?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

> John remembered to call Alex.

Does this sentence imply that John called Alex? Or does it merely mean that John remembered that he needs to make a call? That is, is the sentence

> John remembered to call Alex but John did not call Alex.

contradictory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordinary meaning of **John remembered to call Alex** is that John did call Alex, but you can also write lots of sentences like **John remembered to call Alex but forgot again immediately**.

The ordinary way of separating the remembering and the doing would be constructions such as "John **remembered he wanted to call** Alex, but was distracted and then it was too late."